# Screen split oddly when OS is installed from a Live CD

Tags: installation, ati, live-cd

Never used Linux before but I decided I want to start somewhere and Ubuntu seemed like the right place to start. I burned the 64bit version ISO onto a CD and installed it onto a fresh new hard drive I have. The Live CD works and the Live Distro thing works great. However when I attempt to install it, the screen splits oddly in a way where part of the right is on the left.

Furthermore, after attempting to log in, the GUI doesn't show up and the computer would freeze and stay that way. However you can still move the cursor. I can't really get in or do anything (possibly because I don't know how) and tinker around since I am not too tech savvy. But I can follow instructions.

Graphics Card Radeon hd 6670

I just tried the install with windows thing. There was the exact same problem.

Comment: If you have multiple problems, I suggest asking multiple questions.  And if you want people to give helpful answers, you will need to provide some more details about the symptoms.  For example, I'm not sure what "the screen slip oddly" means.  To start with, consider editing this question to focus on one issue in more detail.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge is right. Please revise your question and provide additional details about your installation problem or booting experience with Ubuntu, so that people will be able to give you useful help and advice. Thank you and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this bug report about freezing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/993187). I ended up doing a kernel change to fix my system.

Comment: JokerDino, I did change my answer I hope this helps the OP

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to Ubuntu and mentioned that you're not too tech savy, I'll leave you with some friendly reading to get you started:

1. [Ubuntu Installation - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)

   > This guide is intended to introduce you to the very many ways in which Ubuntu may be installed to your machine depending on your specific use case.

   *All about the Ubuntu installation process from top to bottom (including the dual boot scenario).*
2. [Ubuntu RadeonDriver - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)

   > This guide will show you how to use the Free, Open Source driver for many ATI graphics cards called "radeon" or "ati". It will provide 2D and 3D acceleration in your video hardware.

   *You mentioned a radeon hd 6670, your graphics card may need a better driver, this should provide the necessary help to confirm, install and use it.*
3. [Ubuntu 32bit_and_64bit - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit)

   > This guide will enlighten you regarding the 32Bit and 64Bit versions of Ubuntu. Hopefully, it will help you decide if your making the right choice for your specific scenario.

---

I know, all of this sounds boring, and you just feel that urge to go ahead, install and use. But if you really want to enjoy the Ubuntu experience, take a couple of minutes to read each document and decide what's best.